# Having links to each entry seperated from each other by a comma

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

I have a table, and one of the columns contains values like `A,B,C` or `D,E` or `F`. Now, what I do is, I have a hyper-link below each entry in this column, and when a user clicks on it, he is re-directed to another page (that I created) with this value being passed to that page form.

However, currently, the hyperlink appears below the complete column value, i.e. it appears under `A,B,C` or `D,E`. Instead, what I want is, it should be per value, i.e. `A`, `B`, `C`. So that when user clicks on it any individual value, he is re-directed using that value instead of the complete value (`A,B,C`). This is the code that I have written right now. 
The table is something like this:

```
      <b-table
        v-if="rows.length"
        :thead-tr-class="'bug-report-thead'"
        :tbody-tr-class="'bug-report-tbody'"
        :items="rows"
        :fields="columnsToDisplay"
        :sort-compare="sortTableByKey"
        :striped="true"
        :bordered="true"
        :outlined="true"
        :hover="true"
        :no-sort-reset="true"
        :show-empty="true"
        :filter="filter"
        @filtered="onFiltered"
        :empty-text="emptyText"
        :sort-desc="true"
        :caption-top="true"
        responsive>
/b-table>

    <template slot="_id" slot-scope="data">
      <a v-if="data.item._id" href="#" @click.prevent="onClickId(data.item._id)">
        {{ data.item._id }}
      </a>
    </template>

    onClickId (id) {
      if (id) {
        this.$router.push({path: `/my-path/my-webpage2/${id}`})
      }
    }
```

`item` here is an object which contains a bunch of attributes. One of the attribute is `ID` and this contains a single string of comma seperated values. 
I want, that when a user clicks on any individual value, he is re-directed using that specific value instead of the entire string.

Can I also have a check so that if in case one of the values is equal to `Hello World`, then the hyperlink will not appear?

Comment: There is a lack of information to answer. What is "date"? What is "item"?
Anyway, it looks like you need a repetition structure (like a v-for) to do what you want.

Comment: @gulima, I have added a couple of clarifications in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using Bootstrap table. In that case, bootstrap table provides a cell `slot`. Since, you want each entry to have hyperlink, you'll need to use this slot to inject the value inside the sell.

Move your `template` inside `<b-table>` and update its slot binding.

```
<b-table {...props}>
  <template v-slot:cell(key)="{value}">
     <a href="#" @click.prevent="onClickId(value)">
    {{ value }}
    </a>
   </template>
</b-table>
```

Keep in mind `key` should be the field's name.